# Supremum and Infimum of $\,S=\{(-1)^k + 2^-k| k≠0 \,\,\text{and}\,\, k>1\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory

Consider $S=\left\{((-1)^k + 2^{-k}|k\in\mathbb{N}k≠0\right\}$

Determine the $Sup(S)$ and $Inf(S)$ and justify.

So far I have that that:

$-1 \lt (-1)^m + 2^{-m}$ $\forall m=2k+1$ (The odd powers of the set)
and

$(-1)^n + 2^{-n} \lt \frac{5}{4}$ $\forall n=2k$ (The even powers of the set)

From here I took the fact that:

$-1-\epsilon \gt (-1)^m + 2^{-m}$  and

$(-1)^n + 2^{-n} \gt \frac{5}{4} -\epsilon$

Then I can break each down and solve for n,m:

I get $-2^{-m} \gt \epsilon$ and

You also get $\epsilon \gt \log\frac{1}{4} + n\log2$

I'm just not sure how this helps in anyway or If I'm even on the right track. Anyone have any ideas? Don't need an answer as much as a kick in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sequences $$\left\langle(-1)^{2n+1}+\frac1{2^{2n+1}}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle=\left\langle-1+\frac1{2^{2n+1}}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\tag{1}$$ and $$\left\langle(-1)^{2n}+\frac1{2^{2n}}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle=\left\langle 1+\frac1{2^{2n}}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle\tag{2}$$ are both decreasing sequences. Every term of $(1)$ is smaller than every term of $(2)$, so the limit of $(1)$ is $\inf S$, and the first term of $(2)$ is $\sup S$; do you see why?